# PHP - Regex find string within square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have the following sample text

```
Some HTML[caption id="attachment_146" align="alignleft" width="450" caption="Annette during 2008 WSOP"]<a href='123'><img src='xxx' /></a>[/caption]More HTML
```

I would like to use regex to identify if the above piece of string contains the caption part ... and if it does I need to extract its attributes and the content within the square brackets i.e. the a tag and img tag

So far I was able to come up with

```
preg_match('^\[caption(.*?)\]^', $content, $matches);
```

Which seems to be able to identify the opening caption 'tag'

Comment: By the way I googled exactly your tile, and found at least 10 answers to that. The answers are all here at SO

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$re = "/\\[caption ([^\\]]*)\\]/"; 
$str = "Some HTML[caption id=\"attachment_146\" align=\"alignleft\" width=\"450\" caption=\"Annette during 2008 WSOP\"][/caption]More HTML"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

This would return:

```
id="attachment_146" align="alignleft" width="450" caption="Annette during 2008 WSOP"
```